# error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘float*’ for argument

Tags: c++, arrays, function

my goal is to pass the arrays to a function, but I get the following error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘float’ to ‘float*’ for argument ‘9’ to ‘void calc_fun(float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, float*, int)’
     calc_fun(rate, hrs_worked, gross, overtime, state_tax,fed_tax, uni_fee, net, total_gross, avg_gross, SIZE);
```

And I don't really understand why, because I think it follows the same steps as `void input_fun(...)` which seems to work perfectly fine.

Additional errors that IDE shows, which might help. (not in debugger, and I use CLion) :

```
calc_fun(rate, hrs_worked, gross, overtime, state_tax, fed_tax, uni_fee, net, total_gross, avg_gross, SIZE);` -> no matching functions for call to "calc_fun" 


void calc_fun(float rate[], float hrs[], float gross[], float overt[], float st_tx[], float fed_tx[], float uni_fee[], float net[], float tgross, float agross, const int S)` -> is never used, I don't understand this one as it's being used in `int main`.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

const float OVERTIME_R = 1.5,
             STATE_TAX = 0.06,
             FED_TAX = 0.12,
             UNION_FEE = 0.02;

const int SIZE = 10;

typedef string INFO;

void input_fun(INFO[], INFO[], INFO[], INFO[], float[], float[], const int);
void calc_fun(float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], const int);

int main()
{
    INFO f_name[SIZE],
         m_name[SIZE],
         l_name[SIZE],
         ID[SIZE];

    float rate[SIZE],
          hrs_worked[SIZE],
          gross[SIZE],
          overtime[SIZE],
          state_tax[SIZE],
          fed_tax[SIZE],
          uni_fee[SIZE],
          net[SIZE],
          total_gross = 0,
          avg_gross = 0;

    input_fun(f_name, m_name, l_name, ID, rate, hrs_worked, SIZE);
    calc_fun(rate, hrs_worked, gross, overtime, state_tax,fed_tax, uni_fee, net, total_gross, avg_gross, SIZE);

    return 0;
}

void input_fun(INFO first[], INFO mid[], INFO last[], INFO id[], float payrate[], float hrs[], const int S)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < S; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter first name of employee    "<<i+1<<" : " << endl;
        cin >> first[i];

        cout << "Enter middle name of employee   "<<i+1<<" : " << endl;
        cin >> mid[i];

        cout << "Enter last name of employee     "<<i+1<<" : " << endl;
        cin >> last[i];

        cout << "Enter the ID of employee        "<<i+1<<" : " << endl;
        cin >> id[i];

        cout << "Pay rate of employee " << i+1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> payrate[i];

        if(payrate[i] < 0 || payrate[i] > 50)
        {
            while(payrate[i] < 0 || payrate[i] > 50)
            {
                cout << "Must be between 0 and 50: " << endl;
                cin >> payrate[i];
            }
        }

        cout << "Hours of work by employee " << i+1 << ": " << endl;
        cin >> hrs[i];

        if(hrs[i] < 0 || hrs[i] > 60)
        {
            while(hrs[i] < 0 || hrs[i] > 60)
            {
                cout << "Must be between 0 and 60: " << endl;
                cin >> hrs[i];
            }
        }

    }

}

void calc_fun(float rate[], float hrs[], float gross[], float overt[], float st_tx[], float fed_tx[], float uni_fee[],
        float net[], float tgross, float agross, const int S){
    for (int i = 0; i < S; i++) {
        if (hrs[i] > 40) {
            overt[i] = (hrs[i] - 40.0) * rate[i] * OVERTIME_R;
        }

        gross[i] = (rate[i] * hrs[i]) + overt[i];

        st_tx[i] = gross[i] * STATE_TAX;
        fed_tx[i] = gross[i] * FED_TAX;
        uni_fee[i] = gross[i] * UNION_FEE;
        net[i] = gross[i] - (st_tx[i] + fed_tx[i] + uni_fee[i]);

        tgross += gross[i];
        agross = tgross / S;

    }
}
```

Comment: The error message from the compiler is clear. The 9-th argument is expected to be a `float*`. You are passing a `float`.

Comment: @RSahu But why is expected to be `float*`. what makes it any different from other arguments.

Comment: at 9 arguments for the function you may want to consider aggregating your data into a structure and having a single array of that structure. The side benefits can be enormous.

Comment: @user4581301 I wish I could, but professor doesn't allow it for this assignment since we have not gone over the structures.

Comment: @DavidGordeladze -- Look at your function *declaration*.   You wrote it to have the 9th argument as `float *`.  Also, specifying `float []` as a parameter is no different than specifying `float *`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I see. you're right. That fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> void calc_fun(float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], float[], const int);
> // scroll right                                                                                ^^^^^^^
> ```

You've declared this argument to be a pointer.

> ```
> float /* snip */
>       total_gross = 0,
> ```

You've declared `total_gross` to be a `float`. It is not an array, and it is not a pointer.

> ```
> calc_fun(rate, hrs_worked, gross, overtime, state_tax,fed_tax, uni_fee, net, total_gross, avg_gross, SIZE);
> // scroll right                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

You pass `total_gross` as an argument that you declared to be a pointer. The types do not match.